# How to cout elapsed time without repeat in SFML?

Tags: c++, sfml

Here is my code:

```
...
sf::Clock clock;
float time = 0.f;

while(window.isOpen())
{
  time = clock.getElapsed().asSeconds();
  cout << (int)time << endl;
}
...
```

This is the output I am getting:

```
0
0
0
0
1
1
1
1
```

As you can see from the above output, each second is getting logged multiple times, and I just want it to be displayed once like below:

```
0
1
2
3
```

Code from link in comment:

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(1280, 720), "SFML works!");
    sf::Clock clock;
    float dt = 0.f;
    int lastTime = 0;
    int currentTime = 0;

    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        dt = clock.getElapsedTime().asSeconds();
        lastTime = (int)dt;
        currentTime = lastTime;

        sf::Event event;
        while (window.pollEvent(event))
        {
            if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
                window.close();
        }

        window.clear();
        window.display();

        
        if(currentTime!=lastTime)
            cout << (int)dt << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Keep track of the last value you printed and only print a new one when it is different.

Comment: tried doing just that but no luck, can you please provide an example if possible?

Comment: Show how you tried that.

Comment: here you go https://pastebin.com/imSnMnDt

Comment: i know its wrong because the value across all the vars (lastTime, currentTime, dt) would be the same in each loop

Comment: You want something more like `currentTime = (int)dt;` and then inside the body of `if(currentTime!=lastTime)` set `lastTime = currentTime;`. Make sure you add braces to the `if`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are inside a while, you have a cout inside it! so it will print all the time, and convert each time(milliseconds) to seconds!

for this purpose you need to use a timer or an easier method, save the last time and +it with 1000 milliseconds and check it inside your while condition.

as a pseudo code:

```cpp
int time = 0;
int last_time = 0;

while(window.isOpen())
{​  
  if(time > last_time){
     cout << time << endl;
  }
  last_time = time;
  time = clock.getElapsed().asSeconds();
}
```

Comment: This is the right idea, but `time` and `last_time` should be `int` since whole seconds are the desired interval.

Comment: Yes, I just didn't want to change his code, but yeah int is better

Comment: im sorry but its not working (still the same repeated second issue), maybe i am doing something wrong? can you please provide a full working example?

Comment: you were right, now it's working correctly. just needed casting to int, btw, if you like it to be more C++ than C, instead of `(int)` you can use `static_cast<int>(YOUR_VARIABLE);`

Comment: alright, that worked! thanks, marked yours as the right answer

Comment: So many casts for no good reason at all. If you want to know if the int value changed and you're going to print an int just use an int!

Comment: Ok @RetiredNinja thank you for advice, I will change the answer with just int. however static_cast will be done at compile time, so there isn't a performance issue with it, and I don't know if he uses the time variable (float) later in other sections or not, so I just wanted to keep his code as it is, but yeah if it's the only usage he's expected from time, it should be just an int.